# Can I set IDLE to start Python 2.5 by default?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-idle, python-2.5, coexistence

Ok, so I just installed Python 2.7, but I all ready had python 2.5. I realized that because I installed Python 2.7 last, IDLE automatically opens Python 2.7 IDLE, which I don't want. Is there any way to set the Python 2.5 IDLE to automatically open when I use the right click option on a python source file? Thanks.

Comment: Windows? Linux? Mac? If on Windows, right-click -> Property and change the file association to the older IDLE, that should do it.

Comment: No because the Open With IDLE is a custom option in the right click menu. I can change what it opens with, but now what that option does.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can easily create or edit the right-click properties for a file.

To edit the right-click menu for a particular file extension:

1. Run `assoc .py` from the command line and note the name of the association:

   > C:>assoc .py
   >   .py=Python.File
2. Run `regedit.exe`.
3. Browse to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell`.
4. Create a key under `shell` called `Edit with IDLE` (or however you want it to show up in the menu).
5. Create a key under `Edit with Idle` called `command`.
6. Edit the default value to run the command you want.  Use `"%1"` to insert the name of the right-clicked file.  Something like:

   > c:\python25\pythonw.exe c:\python25\lib\idlelib\idle.pyw "%1"

Alternatively, just save the following as `idle.reg` and double-click it to insert this value in the registry.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell\Edit with IDLE\command]
@="\"C:\\Python25\\pythonw.exe\" \"C:\\python25\\Lib\\idlelib\\idle.pyw\" \"%1\""
```

Answer (score -1):

Unless you need Python 2.7 for some reason, the simplest way to achieve this in Windows is to uninstall Python and reinstall Python 2.5 again.