# How do I change my python idle and general version from 3.4.3 to 2.7.9

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

I have been searching for answers and have not found any.I was wondering how i could change the default idle to 2.7.9. I downloaded 3.4.3 first and now I don't know how to change to 2.7.9. I want to change so i can run Pygame.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I set IDLE to start Python 2.5 by default?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12443510/can-i-set-idle-to-start-python-2-5-by-default)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on console, write `idle` then press tab:

`$ idle`<kbd>TAB</kbd>

```
idle            idle-python2.7
```

it will spit out the python idle versions on your path: maybe `idle-python2.7` is what you want?

You can actually directly write `idle-python2.7` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>: if there is python idle for that version, it will start.